# Json Encode or Serialize an XML

Tags: php, xml, json, simplexml

I have some xml, this is a simple version of it.

```
<xml>
<items>
  <item abc="123">item one</item>
  <item abc="456">item two</item>
</items>
</xml>
```

Using SimpleXML on the content,

```
 $obj = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
```

I can use `$obj->xpath( '//items/item' );` and get access to the @attributes.

I need an array result, so I have tried the `json_decode(json_encode($obj),true)` trick, but that looks to be removing access to the @attributes (ie. abc="123").

Is there another way of doing this, that provides access to the attributes and leaves me with an array?

Comment: "I need an array result" - why? What format do you need it to be in? If you don't mind what format it's in, then just store `$item->asXML();` and re-parse it next time.

Comment: other methods I'm handing the data to expect a standard array format

Comment: Then how would any built-in PHP function know what that "standard array format" needs to look like? Your code needs to parse the input *you* expect into the output *you* need.

Comment: IMSoP, I'll read through all your SimpleXML topics and hopefully pick up a few pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go the route with `json_encode` and `json_decode` and you can add the stuff you're missing because that `json_encode`-ing follows some specific rules with `SimpleXMLElement`.

If you're interested into the rules and their details, I have written two blog-posts about it:

- [SimpleXML and JSON Encode in PHP – Part I](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-i/)
- [SimpleXML and JSON Encode in PHP – Part II](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-ii/)

For you perhaps more interesing is the third part which shows how you can modify the json serialization and provide your own format (e.g. to preserve the attributes):

- [SimpleXML and JSON Encode in PHP – Part III and End](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-iii-and-end/)

It ships with a full blown example, here is an excerpt in code:

```
$xml = '<xml>
<items>
  <item abc="123">item one</item>
  <item abc="456">item two</item>
</items>
</xml>';

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'JsonXMLElement');

echo $json = json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";

print_r(json_decode($json, TRUE));
```

Output of JSON and the array is as following, note that the attributes are part of it:

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": [
            {
                "@attributes": {
                    "abc": "123"
                },
                "@text": "item one"
            },
            {
                "@attributes": {
                    "abc": "456"
                },
                "@text": "item two"
            }
        ]
    }
}
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [abc] => 123
                                )

                            [@text] => item one
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [abc] => 456
                                )

                            [@text] => item two
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the recursive function in Part III would work just as well as a standalone function, without any reference to JSON. It would also look much the same using DOM or XMLReader APIs. I remain unconvinced of the value of generic conversions like this over using available APIs to traverse the XML in situation-specific ways.

Comment: Well right. Part III says on top that that function replaces the array cast, so sure this works without JSON serialization. If you pick the decorator at the bottom (*Cutting The Gordian Knot*), and you ensure that the work on `$decorator` actually gives back as well the array (instead of just doing the assignment to it), this just does it. You then could name it `ArraySimpleXMLElementSerializer` or something :)

Comment: @hakre Yeah; I think it would be more powerful to present this as *an alternative* to SimpleXML+json_encode, rather than implying that somehow it "fixes" it. Incidentally, I posted a couple of comments (slightly critical, but hopefully not offensive) below those posts, under my real name, but I think they got eaten by a spam-filter.

Comment: @IMSoP: I could not find your comment on my blog, neither in SPAM or in standard lineup. Sorry. Also checked mails where I get copies but just nothing. Maybe the wrong site?

Comment: @hakre Oh well, maybe wordpress.com silently ate them; I've heard rumours it does that sometimes. Thanks for looking; maybe I'll try again at some point.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, it's frustrating a bit.

Comment: @hakre How do you deal with the object vs array issue?  That is, when you've got sibling elements with identical names, an array is created to contain each sibling.  However, if there is only one such element, an object is created.  So, when I've got XML where I might expect 0, 1, or more child elements of a specific name, in the case of 1 element I won't get the array I expect.  This creates a corner case that prevents general array access in all cases.

Comment: The code is pretty well documented and you should be able to modify it to your needs, including having always an array that contains (0?) 1....n elements. However most often in the leaves, there are not duplicate elements therefore you need to decide in the end if not a DOM is a better model and XML just right for serialization :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call attributes() function.

Sample code:

```
$xmlString = '<xml>
<items>
  <item abc="123">item one</item>
  <item abc="456">item two</item>
</items>
</xml>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach( $xml->items->item as $value){
$my_array[] =  strval($value->attributes());
}

print_r($my_array);
```

[Eval](https://eval.in/46237)

Comment: I need an array result, so I'm guessing I'll need to build an array myself?  Because json_encode() strips the attributes?

Comment: As I suspected.  I was hoping maybe there was some json_encode() trick, or related function that could keep the attributes when converting an object to an array.  Thanks!

Comment: The approach seems sound, but this code is odd. Why are you using `$xml->items->item[$i++]` rather than `$value`? And why assign `$xmlitems` just to loop over it when `foreach ( $xml->items->item as $value )` would work just as well?

Comment: Oh, also, `strval($foo->attributes())` will always return the string `'array'`. I'm guessing your intention was to apply `strval` to *each attribute* rather than the list as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
```

$xml is now an object. To get the value of an attribute:

```
$xml->something['id'];
```

Where 'id' is the name of the attribute.

Comment: I need an array result.  I'll be storing this and want to retrieve it at some point.  I want the attributes to be there in the array after I json_decode or unserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

While it's theoretically possible to write a generic conversion from XML to PHP or JSON structures, it is very hard to capture all the subtleties that might be present - the distinction between child elements and attributes, text content alongside attributes (as you have here) or even alongside child elements, multiple child nodes with the same name, whether order of child elements and text nodes is important (e.g. in XHTML or DocBook), etc, etc.

If you have a specific format you need to produce, it will generally be much easier to use an API - like SimpleXML - to loop over the XML and produce the structure you need.

You don't specify the structure you want to achieve, but the general approach given your input would be to loop over each item, and either access known attributes, or loop over each attribute:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
$final_array = array();
foreach ( $sxml->items->item as $xml_item )
{
    $formatted_item = array();

    // Text content of item
    $formatted_item['content'] = (string)$xml_item;

    // Specifically get 'abc' attribute
    $formatted_item['abc'] = (string)$xml_item['abc'];
    // Maybe one of the attributes is an integer
    $formatted_item['foo_id'] = (int)$xml_item['foo_id'];

    // Or maybe you want to loop over lots of possible attributes
    foreach ( $xml_item->attributes() as $attr_name => $attr_value )
    {
         $formatted_item['attrib:' . $attr_name] = (string)$attr_value;
    }

    // Add it to a final list
    $final_array[] = $formatted_item;
    // Or maybe you want that array to be keyed on one of the attributes
    $final_array[ (string)$xml_item['key'] ] = $formatted_item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I've found that is able to process XML into array very nicely: http://outlandish.com/blog/xml-to-json/ ([backup](https://gist.github.com/tautrimas/6698151)). Converting to json is a matter of a `json_encode()` call.