# When using simplexml_load_string all the nodes are of type string... a way to convert to int, float, etc

Tags: php, xml, mongodb, object

I get an XML response from an API and I use simplexml_load_string to convert it to an object in PHP. I then store the object into a mongo database directly and it works perfect. The issue is since it comes from XML all the nodes are of type "string" in mongo. Is there a fancy or simple way to loop through all the nodes in the PHP object and convert to integer or float or boolean? If I pull out all the nodes manually I can use "intval" and "floatval" but I am looking to see if it may be possible to do this automatically based on the content. ie. Loop through all the nodes regardless of depth and do a preg_match for 0-9 to set the item to type "int". If 0-9 w/ . set to float. If true/false/0/1 set to bool. Leave the rest strings. Any ideas?

```
$this->response_object  = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Values in SimpleXML are always of type string within PHP. And due to the magic nature of the `SimpleXMLElement` class, you can not change that by extending from it.

However, you can extend from `SimpleXMLElement` and add a function called `typecastValue()` (exemplary) which does the work. You then can specify with `simplexml_load_string` that you want to use that class instead of the default `SimpleXMLElement` class.

```
class MyElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function typecastValue() {
        $value = trim($this);

        // check if integer, set as float
        if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', $value)){
            return floatval($value);
        }

        // check if float/double
        if (preg_match('/^[0-9\.]{1,}$/', $value)){
            return floatval($value);
        }

        // check if boolean
        if (preg_match('/(false|true)/i', $value)){
            return (boolean)$value;
        }

        // all else leave as string
        return $value;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code is very similar to your typecast function above, it just uses `$this` to obtain the original value.

Functions like `xml_object_to_array` are still generally superfluous, as the parsing is already done and you're more concerned about accessing and serializing the date in the XML into an array (I suspect this is due to JSON requirements of Mongodb but I don't know). If so, [*PHP JSON Serialization*](http://php.net/jsonserializable.jsonserialize) would/could be more appropriate, for `SimpleXMLElement` we have existing material on the site already.

- [Json Encode or Serialize an XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18549388/367456)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer (unless you have a more elegant way)...

```
function xml_object_to_array($xml) {
  if ($xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
    $children = $xml->children();
    $return = null;
  }

  foreach ($children as $element => $value) {
    if ($value instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
      $values = (array)$value->children();

      if (count($values) > 0) {
        $return[$element] = xml_object_to_array($value);
      } else {
        if (!isset($return[$element])) {
          $return[$element] = typecast_value($value);
        } else {
          if (!is_array($return[$element])) {
            $return[$element] = array($return[$element], typecast_value($value));
          } else {
            $return[$element][] = typecast_value($value);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (is_array($return)) {
    return $return;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// auto typecast value for mongo storage
function typecast_value($value){
  $value = trim($value);
  // check if integer, set as float
  if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', $value)){
    return floatval($value);
  }
  // check if float/double
  if(preg_match('/^[0-9\.]{1,}$/', $value)){
    return floatval($value);
  }
  // check if boolean
  if(preg_match('/(false|true)/i', $value)){
    return (boolean)$value;
  }
  // all else leave as string
  return $value;
}
```