# How to get past login screen on Guzzle call

Tags: php, curl, laravel, guzzle

I have to send information to an external website using cURL. I set up Guzzle on my Laravel application. I have the basics set up, but according to the documentation of the website, there is an action that's required for the username and password. How can I pass the 'action' along with the credentials needed to log in and get access?

**The website states:**

`curl [-k] –dump-header <header_file> -F “action=login” -F “username=<username>” -F “password=<password>” https://<website_URL>`

**My controller:**

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->get('http://website.com/page/login/', array(
        'auth' => array('username', 'password')
    ));

    $xml = $response;
    echo $xml;
```

The website will load on the `echo`, but it will only pull up the login screen. I need those credentials to bypass the login screen (with a successful login) to get to the portion of information I need for cURL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`curl -F` submits a POST request instead of a GET request. So you'll need to modify your code accordingly, something like

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post('http://website.com/page/login/', [
    'body' => [
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'cookies' => true
]
);

$xml = $response;
echo $xml;
```

See http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#post-requests, http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

Edit:

Just add `['cookies' => true]` to requests in order to use the auth cookie associated with this `GuzzleHttp\Client()`. http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#cookies

```
$response2 = $client->get('http://website.com/otherpage/', ['cookies' => true]);
```

Comment: Using what you suggest I still get only the login page. Not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Just to be sure, you can successfully perform a cURL request against the url with the given command, correct?

Comment: I think so, when I echo the $xml variable the page will come up but only to the login screen. It needs to bring up the page but with a successful login. Then I can continue with what I need to do which is send over an xml file

Comment: Sorry, I meant the command in your post. `curl -F "action=login" -F "username=<username>" -F "password=<password>" http://website.com/page/login/` Does that produce the login page or the correct page?

Comment: Yeah, I had to download it and test it on my command prompt. Yeah, it gives me an error stating that the system cannot find the file specified so that must be the problem.

Comment: I just fixed a missing bracket in my code. Can you give it a try now?

Comment: I caught that when I copied the code. That didn't fix it either. I was able to get a response from my cmd line. I removed the <header file> section and got the same response as I did from the PHP side. I am not sure what needs to go in the <header file>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58628/discussion-between-jeremiah-winsley-and-lynx).

Comment: Now that you got a xml response say "<wallet><code>0</code></wallet>" how can I get that in an array format?

Comment: @RoydonD'Souza Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6578969 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley Thanks a lot. The first link was helpful in my case.

Answer (score 13):

I was having trouble getting @JeremiahWinsley's answer to work on newer version of Guzzle so I've updated their code to work as of Guzzle 5.x.

Three major changes are required

- Using `form_params` instead of `body` to prevent the error "Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated."
- Changing the cookies to use the `CookieJar` object
- Use `->getBody()->getContents()` to get the [body of the request](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#response-body)

Here is the updated code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$cookieJar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();

$response = $client->post('http://website.com/page/login/', [
    'form_params' => [
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'cookies' => $cookieJar
]
);

$xml = $response->getBody()->getContents();
echo $xml;
```

And to continue using cookies in future requests, pass in the `cookieJar` to the request:

```
$response2 = $client->get('http://website.com/otherpage/', ['cookies' => $cookieJar]);
```

Answer (score 9):

I was having trouble getting @JeremiahWinsley's and @Samsquanch's answer to work on newer version of Guzzle. So I've updated the code to work as of Guzzle 6.x.

Guzzle 6.x. documents: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/index.html

Here is the updated code:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

try {
        $client = new Client();
        $cookieJar = new CookieJar();

        $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://website.com/page/login/', [
            'form_params' => [
                'username' => 'test@example.com',
                'password' => '123456'
            ],
            'cookies' => $cookieJar
        ]);

        $response2 = $client->request('GET', 'http://website.com/otherpage/', [
            'cookies' => $cookieJar
        ]);

        if ($response2->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $response2->getBody()->getContents();
        } else {
            return "Oops!";
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return 'Caught exception: ', $exception->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: This answer is more recent and works as expected. I'm using something similar in my functional tests.

Comment: working in 2021