# convert cURL for Guzzle to send XML file

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I am trying to convert this cURL script to use it with PHP and Guzzle. I have been able to set the cookie as shown below but I cannot send the xml file I need to afterwards.

**cURL Script**

```
# First, we need to get the cookie
curl [-k] –dump-header <header_file> -F “action=login” -F “username=<username>” -F “password=<password>” https://<website_URL>
# Then, we can use that cookie to upload our orders

# XML Order Upload
curl -b <header_file> -F “import=@<order_file>” http://<website_URL>/importXMLOrder.php
```

This is what I have that sets the cookie. I am not sure what the next part is to actually send the xml file I have.

```
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->post('http://website/login.php', array(
            'body' => array(
                'username' => 'xxxxx',
                'password' => 'xxxxxx'
            ))
    );
```

I have also tried this. However, I get an error message:

```
Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Message\Response::send()


    $request = $client->post('http://website.com/import.php', array(
        'body' => array(
            'file_filed' => fopen('orders.xml', 'r')
        )));
    $response = $request->send();
    $data = $response->xml();

    print_r($data);
```

**Update**

```
    $request = $client->createRequest('POST','http://website.com/import.php', array(
        'body' => array(
            'file_filed' => file_get_contents('orders.xml', 'r')
        )
    ));
    $response = $client->send($request);

    //var_dump($response); die;
    $data = $response->xml();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling `send()` from the wrong class. `send()` is a method of `\GuzzleHttp\Client`. So you need to do `$client->send()` instead.

However, `$client->post()` sends the request as soon as it creates it. If you want to use `send()` then you'll need to replace `post()` with `createRequest()`, as seen here: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#creating-requests

You'll also have problems with the call to `fopen()` which returns a file handle instead of the contents. Try `file_get_contents()` instead.

**Edit:**

In order to set the auth cookie, you'll need a cookie jar. Try the following:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$auth = $client->post('http://website/login.php', array(
        'body' => array(
            'username' => 'xxxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxxxx'
        ),
        'cookies' => true
        ));
```

Using the same `Client`:

```
$request = $client->createRequest('POST','http://website.com/import.php', array(
    'body' => array(
        'file_filed' => file_get_contents('orders.xml')
    ),
    'cookies' => true
    ));
$response = $client->send($request);

//var_dump($response); die;
$data = $response->xml();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: OK, I updated the question to show what I have so far. It returns the login screen similar to the question you helped me with the other day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089960/how-to-get-passed-login-screen-on-guzzle-call/25120844?noredirect=1#comment39103225_25120844 Where can I set that cookie, true so that it can bypass the login screen?

Comment: it was the same error i got when I tried this. syntax error, unexpected ''cookies'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: Sorry, should have saw that myself. It's still not working however. Still showing the same message. Requiring login

Comment: OK, i was able to get past the login screen I forgot to set cookies to true on the login page. Now, however the file will not upload it just goes to the import.php page itself

Comment: Make sure you're submitting to the correct page, then. Assuming it's the same site, `http://xxxxxxxx/WMS/weborders/importXMLOrder.php`. The xml should be loaded to the post variable `import` rather than `file_filed`, according to their API guide. Also, `file_get_contents()` doesn't take a second parameter. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: looks like that did it! I was successfully able to send it over. It only worked once and is no longer working but I may be able to figure out the reason why. Thanks a million for the help!

Comment: you can use $response->getBody()->getContents()