# convert URL xml response to PHP array

Tags: php, xml

I am getting xml from https://automap.precisionplanting.com/v1/farms/ and now i want to convert it into php array. I have tried many code but no success. Following some of code examples i have implemented.

```
$url = "https://automap.precisionplanting.com/v1/farms/";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($feed);
```

I want to get output in php array and i have tried different ways for it. above i have shown one example.

What can be error in this? how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Comment: It is giving Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\demo.php on line 9

Comment: could you post beginning of file you are giving to simplexml_load_string (fevw lines)? When i'm going on this page I've get log in page

Comment: try to open https://automap.precisionplanting.com/v1/farms/ and from this URL you will get XML data