# convert xml text array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am using an API and after submit something that API responds me an xml text array:

```
$myArray =  array(
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>",
    "<invoices>",
    "  <invoice>",
    "    <name>Odin</name>",
    "    <zip>0000</zip>",
    "    <city>Asgard</city>",
    "    <lines>",
    "      <line>",
    "        <itemNo>1</itemNo>",
    "        <qty>1.00</qty>",
    "        <prodCode>usb01T</prodCode>",
    "        <desc>USB 1TB</desc>",
    "        <unitPrice>1000.00</unitPrice>",
    "        <tax>25</tax>",
    "        <lineTaxAmount>250.00</lineTaxAmount>",
    "        <lineTotal>1250.00</lineTotal>",
    "      </line>",
    "    </lines>",
    "    <optional>",
    "      <invoiceType>ordinary</invoiceType>",
    "      <invoiceNo>9</invoiceNo>",
    "      <orderNo>119</orderNo>",
    "      <invoiceDate>07.08.15</invoiceDate>",
    "      <dueDate>21.08.15</dueDate>",
    "      <orderDate>07.08.15</orderDate>",
    "      <state>sent</state>",
    "      <recipientNo>119</recipientNo>",
    "      <address1>Valhalla</address1>",
    "      <country>NORGE</country>",
    "      <email>test@vallhalla.com</email>",
    "      <phone>000000</phone>",
    "      <yourRef>Asgard</yourRef>",
    "      <tax>250.00</tax>",
    "      <total>1250.00</total>",
    "      <accountNo>97101013352</accountNo>",
    "      <orgNo>0000000</orgNo>",
    "      <dunningFee>65.00</dunningFee>",
    "      <interestRate>9.00</interestRate>",
    "    </optional>",
    "  </invoice>","</invoices>"
);
```

I want to convert that array to associative array so it will look like:

```
$myArray = array(
            'invoices' => array(
                   'invoice' => array(
                       'name' => 'Odin',
                       'zip' => '0000',
            .....
)
```

I tried json_decode(json_encode($myArray), true) but it fails. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Google: `PHP SimpleXMLElement` <- That should be a good start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that as it stands, your array is simply an array of lines rather than a correct XML array, hence your issues parsing it.

To solve this issue, simply concatenate `$myArray` and parse it as XML before running it through your JSON encoding:

```
$myArray = implode($myArray);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($myArray);
$myArray = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true));
```

Good luck!