# How to convert xml file to php array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I've got strange `xml` file like this http://xxx.pl/tmp/tabela.xml, and I don't know how to convert it into an array. I tried something like this:

```
<?php
$get = file_get_contents('http://xxx.pl/tmp/tabela.xml');
$arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
$data = $arr -> druzyna;
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>pozycja</th>
        <th>pkt</th>
        <th>mecze</th>
        <th>zwyciestwa</th>
        <th>porazki</th>
        <th>wygrane w domu</th>
        <th>przegrane w domu</th>
        <th>wygrane na wyjezdzie</th>
        <th>przegrane na wyjezdzie </th>
        <th>kosze zdobyte</th>
        <th>kosze stracone</th>
        <th>stosunek zdobytych punktów do straconych punktów</th>
        <th>pelna nazwa klubu</th>
        <th>logo klubu</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->pozycja ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->pkt ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->mecze ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->zwyciestwa ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->porazki ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->wygrane_dom ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->przegrane_dom ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->wygrane_wyjazd ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->przegrane_wyjazd ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->kosze_zdobyte ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->kosze_stracone ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->stosunek_zdob_strac ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->pelna_nazwa ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->logo; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

but it's not working.

I read something about `json` solution, but i don't know how to use it, however I met first time `xml` format like that.

I think that this topic [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php) isn't solution of my problem, because i've got another xml file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplexml_load_string returns an [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object. You can query the object (search your data) by using the [xpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) function.

Because of how your XML file is set up, the values are set as attributes.
So you need to retrieve the attributes before you can read them.

```
    <?php

    $get = file_get_contents('http://xxx.pl/tmp/tabela.xml');
    $arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
    $data = $arr->xpath('tabela/druzyna');

    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>pozycja</th>
            <th>pkt</th>
            <th>mecze</th>
            <th>zwyciestwa</th>
            <th>porazki</th>
            <th>wygrane w domu</th>
            <th>przegrane w domu</th>
            <th>wygrane na wyjezdzie</th>
            <th>przegrane na wyjezdzie </th>
            <th>kosze zdobyte</th>
            <th>kosze stracone</th>
            <th>stosunek zdobytych punktów do straconych punktów</th>
            <th>pelna nazwa klubu</th>
            <th>logo klubu</th>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach($data as $row) : ?>
            <?php
            $row = $row->attributes();
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->pozycja ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->pkt ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->mecze ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->zwyciestwa ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->porazki ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->wygrane_dom ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->przegrane_dom ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->wygrane_wyjazd ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->przegrane_wyjazd ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->kosze_zdobyte ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->kosze_stracone ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->stosunek_zdob_strac ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->pelna_nazwa ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->logo; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
```

Comment: moorscode yours solution is brilliant, but now, how can I separate two tables?  <tabela runda="Tabela Stosunek"> and  <tabela runda="Runda Zasadnicza">  ????

Comment: Using xpath you can specifically search for items and even attributes like 'runda'. `$data = $arr->xpath('tabela/druzyna/[@runda="Tabela Stosunek"]');`

Comment: I'm really appreciate for your help but it's not working... I'm trying another like $data = $arr->xpath('tabela/druzyna/@runda="Tabela Stosunek"');  without "@" etc....

Comment: Sorry, the attribute is part of the 'tabela' so it must be placed there in the xpath query: `$data = $arr->xpath('tabela[@runda="Tabela Stosunek"]/druzyna');`

Comment: I am truly thankful.. Thank you so much..

Comment: You are very welcome, can you accept the answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a normal xml, please try this

```
 $url = "http://example.com/tmp/tabela.xml";
 $xml = file_get_contents($url);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($xml);
```