# how pull the xml sting to get back 1 array .. but there is a many value in tag

Tags: php, xml, soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CallTHIResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CallTHIResult>string</CallTHIResult>
    </CallTHIResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

***********************************************
CallTHIResult return value : <TRAN_ID>17560_41206.6291_9568</TRAN_ID><TRAN_DATE>20160128</TRAN_DATE><TRAN_TIME>11:26:46</TRAN_TIME><ERROR_CODE>1</ERROR_CODE><ERROR_DESC>Not Input Policy</ERROR_DESC><POLICY_NBR></POLICY_NBR><URL_POLICY>http://test.php/xxx.pdf</URL_POLICY>
```

I can not get the value for array management into the fileds database.

Comment: you can use `xml_parse_into_struct()`  for convert xml string into array

Comment: Find your answer from here :---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php

Comment: I then test drive the preview can not be pulled up to use it.
  Which is required as the parameter.
        $ trans_id =?
        $ trans_date =?
       etc.

Comment: The problem is that the xml sting has been drawn back 1 array .. but there is a value tag, however.

host return xml sting 1 array.. but many value

ex : <TRAN_ID>17561_54057.6506_1271</TRAN_ID><TRAN_DATE>20160129</TRAN_DATE><TRAN_TIME>15:00:57</TRAN_TIME><ERROR_CODE>1</ERROR_CODE><ERROR_DESC>Not Input Policy</ERROR_DESC><POLICY_NBR></POLICY_NBR><URL_POLICY>http://aiiapp.asiainsurance.co.th/THI_WEB2/webprint/.pdf</URL_POLICY>


i can't get variable in xml string