# Reading tags from xml file into php array

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to display a list of all the tags in a XML file. But I can't seem to do it. [

This is the XML I am tying to read the tags from:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bYHi.png

If someone knows a way to keep the tree struckture of the xml file and trasfer it into an array. That would be really helpfull.

My question is different because I don't know the contents of the xml file. My image is just an example. I am looking for a solution that reads all the tags from an xml file and also keeps the tree structure when putting it in an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert xml into array in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20431742/487813 is probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: are duplicate tags allowed in your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use xml_parser_create, so you could do the following

```
$yourxmlfile = "pathto/yourfilename.xml";
$xmldata = file_get_contents($yourxmlfile);
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmldata, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

print_r($vals);
```

that should print the xml structure as an array, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php for more info about it

Comment: glad I could help :-)