# Parse This Json Array - Unable to get the values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need the Values of all the company names , How can I get It ...

Here is the output of json ...

```html
Array
(
    [version] => 2
    [query] => web developer
    [location] => Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh
    [paginationPayload] => 
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [company] => IBM
                    [country] => IN
                    [date] => Mon, 02 Apr 2017 07:10:15 GMT
                    [formattedRelativeTime] => 4 days ago
                    [stations] => 
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [company] => IPRISM
                    [country] => IN
                    [date] => Mon, 01 Apr 2017 07:10:15 GMT
                    [formattedRelativeTime] => 5 days ago
                    [stations] => 
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [company] => Sunlife
                    [country] => IN
                    [date] => Mon, 03 Apr 2017
                    [formattedRelativeTime] => 3 days ago
                    [stations] => 
                )
     )
)
```

I need the Value of Every Company Listed Here In New Line ,

IBM
IPRISM
Sunlife

Comment: I am able to get values using this : echo $obj['results'][0]['jobtitle'] , but I need this is Foreach format ..

Comment: Can you tell me what language you are using?

Comment: You mention `foreach`. Have you tried using it? It seems the answer is "go follow some programming tutorials"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use foreach loop to achieve your result

```
 foreach($array['results'] as $company){
     echo $company['company'].'<br />';
 }
```

change the name `$array` with your actual array variable

Comment: This Worked ... Thanks

Comment: Hey , How to get the sdImg usig SimpleXML 
, <item sdImg="/A00000001A8.jpg" hdImg="/A00000001A8.jpg" >
<title>ABC</title>
<slNo>79</slNo>
<contentId>424</contentId>
</item>

<item sdImg="/A00000007A8.jpg" hdImg="/A00000007A8.jpg" >
<title>ABC1</title>
<slNo>99</slNo>
<contentId>427</contentId>
</item>

Comment: @SharonMoore, you have to use `SimpleXMLElement()` please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6578969/3894567

Answer (score 1):

> @Sharon Moore try array_column():

```
echo implode(" ", array_column($yourArray["results"], "company"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($obj['results'] as $data)  // On each iteration $data will be updated with 0, 1, 2 index values
{
    echo $data['jobtitle'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you could try this**

```
 foreach ($data['result'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['company'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
$i=0;
foreach($obj['results'] as $res){

echo $res[$i]['company'];
$i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below:

```
foreach($arr['results'] as $company)
{
    echo $company['company'];
}
```