# How to get a Specific part from a Query in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this value

```
$result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="123" name="Demo Name" gender="M" yob="2000" gname="Abdul Mannan" lm="city" vtc="City2" po="norway" dist="california" subdist="Ny" state="US" pc="12345" dob="22/06/2000"/>';
```

and i want the uid,name,gneder,yob,gname, lm Value and so on.

Comment: _I have this value....i want the uid..._ What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php  Explains it very well

Comment: `simplexml_load_string($result);`, then attributes can be accessed using `['uid']` for example.

Comment: what's the status of this question? there's an answer below which to me looks like a possible solution. You didn't comment and/or accepted it, given if it was the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `simplexml_load_string()` before, so I thought I'd take the opportunity to self-educate.

After a combination of reading Doomenik's posted link, reading the manual on `simplexml_load_string()`, and running some tests on 3v4l.org, this seems to be a direct/advisable solution:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S8nsc))

```
$result='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="123" name="Demo Name" gender="M" yob="2000" gname="Abdul Mannan" lm="city" vtc="City2" po="norway" dist="california" subdist="Ny" state="US" pc="12345" dob="22/06/2000"/>';
$array=json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($result)),true);
foreach($array['@attributes'] as $k=>$v){
    echo "<div>$k : $v</div>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<div>uid : 123</div>
<div>name : Demo Name</div>
<div>gender : M</div>
<div>yob : 2000</div>
<div>gname : Abdul Mannan</div>
<div>lm : city</div>
<div>vtc : City2</div>
<div>po : norway</div>
<div>dist : california</div>
<div>subdist : Ny</div>
<div>state : US</div>
<div>pc : 12345</div>
<div>dob : 22/06/2000</div>
```

Comment: [I think you have me to thank.... on the green you got for this just now.....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664195/how-to-get-a-specific-part-from-a-query-in-php#comment82361335_46664195) ;-)

Comment: Next beer is on me.