# Parse XML string to JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<corpsms>
    <transaction id="44444774">
        <status num="923337896466" date="14-11-2017 10:02:58">Successful</status>
        <status num="923337897246" date="14-11-2017 10:02:59">Successful</status>
    </transaction>
</corpsms>';
```

Failed to catch 'status num="923337896466"' And failed to catch date="14-11-2017 10:02:58"

JSON output should be like:

```
{
    "transaction id": "44444774",
    "Total status num": "02",
    "status": [
        {
            "status num": "923337896466",
            "date": "14-11-2017 10:02:58",
            "output": "Successful"
        },
        {
            "status num": "923337897246",
            "date": "14-11-2017 10:02:59",
            "output": "Successful"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [transaction] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 44444774
                )

            [status] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Successful
                    [1] => Successful
                )

        )

)

Comment: Show us an attempt at code, so far we're seeing what you have and what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<corpsms>
    <transaction id="44444774">
        <status num="923337896466" date="14-11-2017 10:02:58">Successful</status>
        <status num="923337897246" date="14-11-2017 10:02:59">Successful</status>
    </transaction>
</corpsms>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

The output will be

```
{
    "transaction id": "44444774",
    "Total status num": "02",
    "status": [
        {
            "num": "923337896466",
            "date": "14-11-2017 10:02:58",
            "output": "Successful"
        },
        {
            "num": "923337897246",
            "date": "14-11-2017 10:02:59",
            "output": "Successful"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: failed to get "status num"

Comment: Space between `status` and `num` maybe the issue, Change it to `statusnum` or `status_num`. You will get the result.

Comment: cant change anything because response is coming from 3rd party . where we do not have access .

Comment: @MalikIrfan `num` attribute of `status` element. so you can get the value of `num`

Comment: but how ? i failed to get

Comment: @MalikIrfan What you are getting? Kindly update your question