# Convert an XML file generated with cURL to JSON

Tags: php, json, xml, curl

I am using the [boardgamegeek.com XML API](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/BGG_XML_API) to get the information on a game. I am able to use cURL to retrieve this, but now I have the XML data I don't seem to be able to do anything with it.

This is my cURL code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$id = 226910;
$exp = 1;

$url = 'https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/' . (!$exp ? 'boardgame' : 'boardgameexpansion') . '/' . $id . '/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);
if ($xml == false)
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

And this is my generated output:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<boardgames termsofuse="http://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse">
<boardgame objectid="226910">
<yearpublished>2017</yearpublished>
<minplayers>1</minplayers>
<maxplayers>5</maxplayers>
<playingtime>0</playingtime>
<minplaytime>0</minplaytime>
<maxplaytime>0</maxplaytime>
<age>14</age>
<name primary="true" sortindex="1">Star Trek: Ascendancy – Borg Assimilation</name>
<description>
This page does not exist. You can edit this page to create it.
</description>
<thumbnail>
https://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic3690765_t.jpg
</thumbnail>
<image>https://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic3690765.jpg</image>
<boardgamefamily objectid="12210">4X games</boardgamefamily>
<boardgamemechanic objectid="2001">Action Point Allowance System</boardgamemechanic>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1015">Civilization</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamemechanic objectid="2072">Dice Rolling</boardgamemechanic>
<boardgamedesigner objectid="62674">Aaron Dill</boardgamedesigner>
<boardgameartist objectid="76681">Katie Dillon</boardgameartist>
<boardgameversion objectid="354684">English first edition</boardgameversion>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1020">Exploration</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamepublisher objectid="11420">Gale Force Nine, LLC</boardgamepublisher>
<boardgamedesigner objectid="62672">John Kovaleski</boardgamedesigner>
<boardgamemechanic objectid="2011">Modular Board</boardgamemechanic>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1064">Movies / TV / Radio theme</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1026">Negotiation</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1016">Science Fiction</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1113">Space Exploration</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamefamily objectid="7392">Star Trek</boardgamefamily>
<boardgamedesigner objectid="62673">Sean Sweigart</boardgamedesigner>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1086">Territory Building</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamemechanic objectid="2008">Trading</boardgamemechanic>
<boardgamemechanic objectid="2079">Variable Phase Order</boardgamemechanic>
<boardgamemechanic objectid="2015">Variable Player Powers</boardgamemechanic>
<boardgamecategory objectid="1019">Wargame</boardgamecategory>
<boardgamepodcastepisode objectid="213535">What Did You Play This Week Podcast Week 145</boardgamepodcastepisode>
<boardgameartist objectid="62716">Charles Woods</boardgameartist>
<boardgameexpansion objectid="193949" inbound="true">Star Trek: Ascendancy</boardgameexpansion>
<poll name="suggested_numplayers" title="User Suggested Number of Players" totalvotes="1">
<results numplayers="1">
<result value="Best" numvotes="1"/>
<result value="Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Not Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
<results numplayers="2">
<result value="Best" numvotes="1"/>
<result value="Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Not Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
<results numplayers="3">
<result value="Best" numvotes="1"/>
<result value="Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Not Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
<results numplayers="4">
<result value="Best" numvotes="1"/>
<result value="Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Not Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
<results numplayers="5">
<result value="Best" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Not Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
<results numplayers="5+">
<result value="Best" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="Not Recommended" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
</poll>
<poll name="language_dependence" title="Language Dependence" totalvotes="0">
<results>
<result level="1" value="No necessary in-game text" numvotes="0"/>
<result level="2" value="Some necessary text - easily memorized or small crib sheet" numvotes="0"/>
<result level="3" value="Moderate in-game text - needs crib sheet or paste ups" numvotes="0"/>
<result level="4" value="Extensive use of text - massive conversion needed to be playable" numvotes="0"/>
<result level="5" value="Unplayable in another language" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
</poll>
<poll name="suggested_playerage" title="User Suggested Player Age" totalvotes="1">
<results>
<result value="2" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="3" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="4" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="5" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="6" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="8" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="10" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="12" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="14" numvotes="1"/>
<result value="16" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="18" numvotes="0"/>
<result value="21 and up" numvotes="0"/>
</results>
</poll>
</boardgame>
</boardgames>
```

I have tried changing my code to the following to try and generate a JSON array:

```
<?php
// header('Content-type: text/xml');

$id = 226910;
$exp = 1;

$url = 'https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/' . (!$exp ? 'boardgame' : 'boardgameexpansion') . '/' . $id . '/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response == false)
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($array);
```

But this just throws the following error:

> 2017 1 5 0 0 0 14 Star Trek: Ascendancy – Borg Assimilation This page
>   does not exist. You can edit this page to create it.
>   https://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic3690765_t.jpg 
>   https://cf.geekdo-images.com/images/pic3690765.jpg 4X games Action
>   Point Allowance System Civilization Dice Rolling Aaron Dill Katie
>   Dillon English first edition Exploration Gale Force Nine, LLC John
>   Kovaleski Modular Board Movies / TV / Radio theme Negotiation Science
>   Fiction Space Exploration Star Trek Sean Sweigart Territory Building
>   Trading Variable Phase Order Variable Player Powers Wargame What Did
>   You Play This Week Podcast Week 145 Charles Woods Star Trek:
>   Ascendancy  Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser
>   error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
>   /home/matthew1/public_html/api/index.php on line 19
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): 1 in
>   /home/matthew1/public_html/api/index.php on line 19
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in
>   /home/matthew1/public_html/api/index.php on line 19 bool(false)

(Note the XML data being displayed without `<tags>` before the error message starts.)

Comment: Thanks for the well-explained downvote, anonymous...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of
>   curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)).

Without this option after this assignment `$response = curl_exec($ch);` , the `$response` variable will contain boolean value `true`. Then after executing the code `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);` you get an error:

> `Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag
>   expected, '<' not found`

To send valid XML header use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: text/xml"]);
```