# How to parse this XML using XPath in Php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xpath

I'm trying to parse the XML with XPath, but I'm unable to get data out, kindly help me with a Pseudocode, Need to print the data using XPath in PHP, I'm unable to understand how to print each tag. kindly need some advice regarding this XPath in PHP.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
                     <Report>
                     <section index="2.2" title="Users With A Weak Authentication Password" ref="AUTHENTICATION.USERS.WEAKPASSWORD">
        <issuedetails>
          <devices>
            <device name="AD-FIN-2" type="Cisco Catalyst Switch" osversion="15.0" />
          </devices>
          <ratings type="Nipperv1">
            <rating>High</rating>
            <impact>Critical</impact>
            <ease>Moderate</ease>
            <fix>Quick</fix>
          </ratings>
        </issuedetails>
        <section index="2.2.1" title="Finding" ref="FINDING">
          <text>Access to restricted network user and administration services are typically secured using username and password authentication credentials. The strength of the authentication credentials is even more important if the service allows for devices to be reconfigured or it allows access to potentially sensitive information.</text>
          <text>DWS identified two user accounts with a weak password on AD-FIN-2. These are listed in Table <linktotable ref="AUTHENTICATION.USERS.WEAKPASSWORD.1">8</linktotable> and includes administrative access to the device.</text>
          <table index="8" title="Users on AD-FIN-2 with a weak password" ref="AUTHENTICATION.USERS.WEAKPASSWORD.1">
            <headings>
              <heading>User</heading>
              <heading>Password</heading>
              <heading>Privilege</heading>
              <heading>Weakness</heading>
            </headings>
            <tablebody>
              <tablerow>
                <tablecell><item>enable (password)</item></tablecell>
                <tablecell><item>R@j!magic</item></tablecell>
                <tablecell><item>15</item></tablecell>
                <tablecell><item>No numbers</item></tablecell>
              </tablerow>
              <tablerow>
                <tablecell><item>admin</item></tablecell>
                <tablecell><item>R@j!magic</item></tablecell>
                <tablecell><item>1</item></tablecell>
                <tablecell><item>No numbers</item></tablecell>
              </tablerow>
            </tablebody>
          </table>
        </section>
        <index="2.2.2" title="Impact" ref="IMPACT">
          <text>A malicious user, or remote attacker, who is able to connect to an administrative service will be able to authenticate to the device without using a password. The attacker will then be able to perform administrative and user level tasks. This could include re-configuring the device, extracting potentially sensitive information and disabling the device. Once an attacker has obtained the configuration from the device they may be able to identify authentication credentials that could then be used to gain access to other network devices.</text>
        </section>
        <section index="2.2.3" title="Ease" ref="EASE">
          <text>Password brute-forcing tools and techniques have been widely documented on the Internet and published media. Although there are a number of different tools available, brute-forcing authentication credentials can be problematic.</text>
          <list type="numbererd">
            <listitem>Account lockout facilities can quickly prevent access to the account.</listitem>
            <listitem>Device protection mechanisms may slow or disconnect connections where multiple authentication attempts are made in a short period of time.</listitem>
            <listitem>Brute-forcing can be very time consuming, especially if the password is long or made up of various character types.</listitem>
            <listitem>Network administrators may be alerted to locked out accounts or authentication attempts.</listitem>
          </list>
        </section>
        <section index="2.2.4" title="Recommendation" ref="RECOMMENDATION">
          <text>DWS strongly recommends that all authentication credentials should be configured with a strong password.</text>
          <text>DWS recommends that:</text>
          <list type="bullet">
            <listitem>passwords should be at least eight characters in length;</listitem>
            <listitem>characters in the password should not be repeated more than five times;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include both upper case and lower case characters;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include numbers;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include punctuation characters;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not include the username;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not include a device's name, make or model;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not be based on dictionary words.</listitem>
          </list>
          <text>Notes for Cisco Catalyst Switch devices:</text>
          <text>The following commands can be used on Cisco Catalyst Switch devices to set the enable password, create a local user with a password and to delete a local user:<code><command>enable secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
<command>username <cmduser>user</cmduser> secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
<command>no username <cmduser>user</cmduser></command>
</code></text>
        </section>
      </section>
          </Report>
```

MyCode: This is the code which I have used to parse the XML, but I'm unable to print data out or array? kindly help me with a solution.

```
$xmlContent = file_get_contents('toshibaconfig2.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$dom->loadXml($xmlContent);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//
// Add namespaces automatically
//
// Fetch the namespaces, add a few lines to register these back with the document
// so that you can use them in XPath expressions...
foreach ($xpath->query('namespace::*', $dom->documentElement) as $node) {
    //echo $node-> . '=' . $node->nodeValue, "\n";
    $xpath->registerNamespace($node->localName, $node->nodeValue);
}


// Root node
$rootNode = $xpath->query('/report');

// Finding data
$Intro = $xpath->query('section/issuedetails/text', $rootNode)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$table = $xpath->query('table/headings/tablebody', $rootNode)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$list = $xpath->query('text/list/listitem', $rootNode)->item(0)->nodeValue;

// code data
$itemList = array();
$codedata = $xpath->query('command/cmduser/cmduser', $rootNode);

// Then loop over the items...

/** @var DOMNode $invoiceItemNode */
foreach ($codedata as $codedt) {
    $row = [];

    /** @var DOMNode $field */
    foreach ($codedt->childNodes as $field) {
        $row[$field->tagName] = $field->nodeValue;
    }
    $itemList[] = $row;
}

print_r($itemList);
```

Comment: nice, by the way, what should be the final output? there's a lot of nodes there, you need to be a little bit specific on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I need all  the node in the <Report> ... </report> in the Specific order [Finding],[Ease],[impact],[Recommendation],[tablerow][tablebody],[heading],[command],[cmduser].

Comment: looking at the xml you have it seems you probably have a typo `<index="2.2.2" title="Impact" ref="IMPACT">`, and with the codes there's no `issuedetails` in xml there

Comment: Please check the XML again i have pasted the correct XML  @Ghost

Comment: since you have an unclear array structure, there's a simple one liner that you can use `print_r(json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($xmlContent)),1);)`

Comment: Can Provide with a code and output so that i can get clear idea how u were able to parse the XML, Plus i have pasted the correct XML, so no u can get a clear idea about the XML

Comment: @Ghost is their any other way to print the data ?

Comment: yes there are numerous ways, assuming the structure will always be the same, you can use the same xpath query, like `//table/tablebody` and `//list/listitem`

Comment: actually, i'd suggest this answer by hakre, no need to parse everything, just use this recursive function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15849257/3859027 since your intent is to put everything inside an array

Comment: @Ghost I need it specfically in XPath , not in simple Load string.

Comment: @Ghost Is their any way to print the XML

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for `/report` but the root element of your XML is called `<Report>`. XML is case-sensitive.