# Can you return an array from xml request?

Tags: javascript, php, xml

this is my xml requested page...  I want to return the array of values getting from the query to the javascript function call this request

```
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['val']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','factory');
$aa = 'fact'.$id;
$sql1 = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME LIKE '$aa%' and table_schema='factory';";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
foreach ($result1 as $key) {

how to return the array??
 }

?>
```

Comment: `how to return the array??` by pushing values onto an array

Comment: im new to xml, so can i know how to accept the returning array?

Comment: Just push the values in an array under foreach loop and after that return the array. Simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by preparing a `application/json` response and sending back to the `jQuery` (presume that's what you use).

First you will need to prepare your data array. To do that, you will need to iterate through the query results, like this.

```
$dataArray = array();
foreach ($result1 as $row) {
   $dataArray [] = $row;
}
```

At this point you will have the array loaded with data. Then all you need to do is send back as a `application/json` response.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dataArray);
```

The calling `jQuery` function will look like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "submit.php", success: function(result){
            console.log(result);            
        }});
    });
});
```

The above `console.log` line will dump you the response came from the `PHP` and it will look like this.

```
{ name: "Test Name", description: "Test Desription", date: "22/10/2018"}
```

Please note that above data is based on the following data array. Only for the demonstration purposes.

```
array('name' => 'Test Name', 'description' => 'Test Desription', 'date' => '22/10/2018');
```

I hope this helps, 
Cheers.