# Converting XML object to array in PHP not working

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am using PHP and I have the following XML response from my web-service, it is an XML object and I can convert it to a string too.

How can I get every service  from the XML object above it as an array? 
I tried to use the function below but I got an empty array, any help please?

The XML is as below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <rateresp:RateResponse xmlns:rateresp="http://scxgxtt.phx-dc.dhl.com/euExpressRateBook/RateMsgResponse">
            <Provider code="DHL">
                <Notification code="0">
                    <Message/>
                </Notification>
                <Service type="Q">
                    <TotalNet>
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Amount>197.45</Amount>
                    </TotalNet>
                    <Charges>
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Charge>
                            <ChargeType>MEDICAL EXPRESS</ChargeType>
                            <ChargeAmount>159.19</ChargeAmount>
                        </Charge>
                        <Charge>
                            <ChargeCode>FF</ChargeCode>
                            <ChargeType>FUEL SURCHARGE</ChargeType>
                            <ChargeAmount>28.26</ChargeAmount>
                        </Charge>
                        <Charge>
                            <ChargeCode>II</ChargeCode>
                            <ChargeType>SHIPMENT INSURANCE</ChargeType>
                            <ChargeAmount>10.00</ChargeAmount>
                        </Charge>
                    </Charges>
                    <DeliveryTime>2019-12-02T12:00:00</DeliveryTime>
                    <CutoffTime>2019-11-26T18:00:00</CutoffTime>
                    <NextBusinessDayInd>N</NextBusinessDayInd>
                </Service>
                <Service type="8">
                    <TotalNet>
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Amount>72.00</Amount>
                    </TotalNet>
                    <Charges>
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Charge>
                            <ChargeType>EXPRESS EASY</ChargeType>
                            <ChargeAmount>72.00</ChargeAmount>
                        </Charge>
                    </Charges>
                    <DeliveryTime>2019-12-02T23:59:00</DeliveryTime>
                    <CutoffTime>2019-11-26T18:00:00</CutoffTime>
                    <NextBusinessDayInd>N</NextBusinessDayInd>
                </Service>
            </Provider>
        </rateresp:RateResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

PHP function:

```
function xml2array($xmlObject, $out = array()) {
    foreach ((array) $xmlObject as $index => $node) {
        $out[$index] = ( is_object($node) ) ? xml2array($node) : $node;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Comment: The input xml is object or string? (If that an object, how did you convert it?)

Comment: it is an object

Comment: This is SOAP, XML is only the syntax of the string serialization. Use a SOAP client library.

Comment: I cannot use SOAP that is why I'm asking here