# Why read data with curl I get string value?

Tags: laravel, curl

In laravel 7 app I read data with curl and expect returned data be in json format :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $search_web_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","charset=windows-1251"))
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
\Log::info( '-1 $resp ::' . print_r( $resp, true  ) );
```

But $resp is a string starting with rows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><ItemValues >...</ItemValues>
```

So I got error :

```
 Trying to get property 'ItemValues' of non-object {...
```

on next line :

$ItemValuesRows = json_decode($resp)->ItemValues;

Is my header wrong or which tool to apply to get json rows?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the accept header of the url?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question : do you ask about one of curl parameters? I expected json rows...

Comment: `$search_web_url` what is the accept header of the url passed in this, like you have passed content-type: application/json, similarly there is a content type of accept header

Comment: it's not JSON at all, it's XML. the problem is that you are expecting JSON, but you are getting XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like xml.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($resp, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

based on [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Comment: Thanks, it works but as I set windows-1251 in charset of curl report  in returned data this charset is not supported and I see Unreadable symbols...