# How to parse a xml string to array in PHP?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, php-curl

I am using an API that give me a XML response (with Curl)
I need to parse the response to get a specific value

I follow the php documentation

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

But in my case, the response of the curl is something like this without  <<<XML  XML; tag and simplexml_load_string give me empty object

```
`
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>`;
```

In fact, how I can surround my response with this tag ?

Comment: You may find your answer on this page: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it into associative array by encoding the XML object as JSON and then decoding it back into array like so:

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

$xml = json_encode($xml);
$xml = json_decode($xml, true);
```

Comment: But my initial string hasn't the <<<XML  XML;  tag. How I can add it ?

Comment: Well, I don't think you need to (it's not part of XML). But if you insist, read about the heredoc and nowdoc here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc