# I'm having trouble converting XML into an Array

Tags: php, xml

I'm a novice in PHP so go easy on me ;)

Basically I have an XML file which I'm trying to convert into an Array using PHP. My XML file, *supplies.xml*, looks a bit like this...

```
<Supplies>
    <supply name="Pen">
        <supplier name="Pen Island">http://domain.com/</supplier>
        <quantity>2000</quantity>
        <cost>100.00</cost>
    </supply>
    <supply name="Pencil">
        <supplier name="Stationary World">http://domain.com/</supplier>
        <quantity>5000</quantity>
        <cost>115.30</cost>
    </supply>
    <supply name="Paper">
        <supplier name="Stationary World">http://domain.com/</supplier>
        <quantity>100</quantity>
        <cost>10.50</cost>
    </supply>
</Supplies>
```

I want it converting into an Array with this structure...

```
Array (
    [Pen] => Array (
        [supplier] => Pen Island
        [supplier_link] => http://domain.com/
        [quantity] => 2000
        [cost] => 100
    )
    [Pencil] => Array (
        [supplier] => Stationary World
        [supplier_link] => http://domain.com/
        [quantity] => 5000
        [cost] => 115.3
    )
    [Paper] => Array (
        [supplier] => Stationary World
        [supplier_link] => http://domain.com/
        [quantity] => 100
        [cost] => 10.5
    )
)
```

I tried this but PHP doesn't like it...

```
<?php

    $xml_supplies = simplexml_load_file("supplies.xml");
    $supplies = array();
    foreach ($xml_supplies->Supplies->supply as $supply) {
        $supplies[(string)$supply['name']] = array(
            "supplier" => (string)$supply->supplier['name'],
            "supplier_link" => (string)$supply->supplier,
            "quantity" => (int)$supply->quantity,
            "cost" => (float)$supply->cost
        )
    }

    print_r($supplies);

?>
```

My theory behind it was that it would loop though each *supply* element and add to the *$supplies* Array.

I've spent nearly an hour trying to get it to work but I've given up and would like some help. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578084/how-to-convert-this-xml-request-into-array-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change you code to this:

```
foreach ($xml_supplies->supply as $supply) { ...
```

If you print `$xml_supplies` you will see that it has this structure:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [supply] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Pen
                        )

                    [supplier] => http://domain.com/
                    [quantity] => 2000
                    [cost] => 100.00
                )
            ...
```

so you don't need to prefix your query with the root node `Supplies`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy three-line solution:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("supplies.xml");
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

however, I'd prefer keeping data in SimpleXMLElement object if the conversion to array is not absolutely necessary..