# PHP get data from multilevel tag colon XML file DOM PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have question , how to parsing data from multilevel tag colon XML file with dom PHP. 
Below is my XML sample data. I want to get data inside < transfer > and return as an array data

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <HostCustomerResponse xmlns="http://xx.xx.xx.xx">
      <ns1:output xmlns:ns1="http://xx.xx.xx" xmlns:ns2="some:url" xsi:type="ns2:Output">
       <ns2:statusCode>00</ns2:statusCode>
       <ns2:statusMsg/>
       <ns2:txnResponseDateTime>20190625164236</ns2:txnResponseDateTime>
       <ns2:txnData>
         <transferRequest>
           <transfer>
             <transferId>123456789</transferId>
             <txnDate>123456789</txnDate>
             <debitAcctNo>123456789</debitAcctNo>
             <benAcctNo>123456789</benAcctNo>
          </transfer>
        </transferRequest>
      </ns2:txnData>
    </ns1:output>
   </HostCustomerResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this result i want.

```
array(
  [transferID] => 123456789,
  [txnDate] => 123456789, 
  .....
)
```

Comment: [How to convert xml into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php)

Comment: [How to convert this XML request into array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578084/how-to-convert-this-xml-request-into-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `http://xx.xx.xx.xx` is the real namespace in

```
<HostCustomerResponse xmlns="http://xx.xx.xx.xx">
```

but as this defines the namespace for any default elements (i.e. the ones your after) then you need to load the source XML and then register this namespace.  Then you can use XPath to find the `<transfer>` element.  You then just iterate through the elements within that ( using `children()` and add them into the output array...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "http://xx.xx.xx.xx");
$transfer = $xml->xpath("//d:transfer")[0];
$output = [];
foreach ( $transfer->children() as $key=> $value )  {
    $output[$key] = (string)$value;
}
```

Your original XML is missing the definition of the `soapenv` namespace, so I added that to make the XML correct...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://soapev.com" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <HostCustomerResponse xmlns="http://xx.xx.xx.xx">
      <ns1:output xmlns:ns1="http://xx.xx.xx" xmlns:ns2="some:url" xsi:type="ns2:Output">
       <ns2:statusCode>00</ns2:statusCode>
       <ns2:statusMsg/>
       <ns2:txnResponseDateTime>20190625164236</ns2:txnResponseDateTime>
       <ns2:txnData>
         <transferRequest>
           <transfer>
             <transferId>123456789</transferId>
             <txnDate>123456789</txnDate>
             <debitAcctNo>123456789</debitAcctNo>
             <benAcctNo>123456789</benAcctNo>
          </transfer>
        </transferRequest>
      </ns2:txnData>
    </ns1:output>
   </HostCustomerResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: It's work. Thank you so much ! But if I want to get data like value of <ns2:statusCode> , <ns2:statusMsg> etc, what should I change from the code ?

Comment: You can do a similar thing - register the ns2 namespace `$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns2", "some:url");` and then `$xml->xpath("//ns2:statusMsg")[0]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the transfer node by using the following code  snippet

```
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $soapXMLResult);
$xml      = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$body     = $xml->xpath('//soapenvBody')[0];
$array    = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE); 
$transfer = $array['HostCustomerResponse']['ns1output']['ns2txnData']['transferRequest']['transfer'];
```

https://3v4l.org/UKnZs

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to another XML response, I get some error because the XML tag colon response dynamically change. Thanks dude btw

Comment: @BellyBrata you can use array till index `$array['HostCustomerResponse']['ns1output']['ns2txnData']['transferRequest']` , may be that helps OR any other array index which is common in all the response.